# Issue getting value of php output results with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am attempting to get the value of specific looped elements. I basically have a list of records and if I click on a record, I want to be able to obtain the value of the `status` of that element. The `status` value is binary, either 0 or 1. The issues I am running into are the following:

-The click function I created is not generating a value and the alert is not showing.

-As you can see in my `foreach` loop, I am outputting the `$status_img` for `$status` if it meets a certain condition. The value I need is really `$status`.

Does anyone see what I can do to help my problems?

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $status = $row['status'];
            $class = $status != 0 ? 'status-nonzero' : '';
            if ($status == 0) {
                $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" alt="Goal Not Complete">';
            }
            else {
                $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" alt="Goal Complete">';
            }
            $goal_date = $row['date'];
            $fixed_goal_date = fixDate($goal_date);
            $html = "";
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box-left">';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-status">'.$status_img. '</div>';
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.goal-post-status').click(function (event) {
     var status = $(this).val;
     alert(status);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set status in data-attribute then read it from jQuery:

HTML

```
$html .= '<div class="goal-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
$html .= '<div class="goal-box-left">';
$html .= '<div class="goal-post-status" data-status="'.$status.'">'.$status_img. '</div>';
```

Javascript

```
$("body").on("click", ".goal-post-status", function (event) {
    var status = $(this).attr("data-status");
    alert(status);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but for some reason the alert still isn't showing.

Comment: Can you share problem web-page?

Comment: If you insert this goals via ajax - use this from of event-listening: `$("body").on("click", ".goal-post-status")`. I've fixed solution.

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but for some reason, the check marked icons aren't working. I also noticed that it isn't reading my css rule of `cursor:pointer;` Do you see why that specific one wouldn't work?

Comment: Thanks. I believe it has to do with my element above it that has `opacity:0`. If you click on "Add New Goal", you will see a form appears. I can't figure out how to make that not interfere with this.

Comment: Anyways, your solution helped. I will just have to try and figure out this now.. Thanks!

Comment: Use `.show()` and `.hide()` for your form, it hides it "compleatly"

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
use `$(this).html()` in place of `$(this).val()`

```
 $('body').on('click','.goal-post-status',function (event) {
     var status = $(this).html();
     alert(status);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".goal-post-status").click(this, function() {
    var status = $(this).html();
    alert(status);
});
```